# Remove modulepath eclipse

Tags: java

I want to add Web driver on Build Path bt there are error, so I go to configure build Path to import jar extend. But there are error again and again.

But I deleted module Path and Classpath unintentionally on Eclipse

How to fix that?

Thank !

I dont know to fix that